# How to make sure nuget never update itself automatically?

Tags: nuget

I want to use Nuget in a situation where it should not update itself automatically. How can I configure / enforce this?

It seems Nuget is sometimes updated automatically. From the documentation it seems it is only a matter of not using the -Self option. But this seems to be incorrect. How can this be disabled?

In the Visual Studio Nuget options dialog there is a "Automatically check for updates" checkbox. Where is this setting stored?

Is there some setting / trick to "pin" the Nuget version explicitly?

Comment: Which NuGet are you referring to? NuGet.exe or the plugin for Visual Studio? The "Automatically check for updates" checkbox only affects the plugin for Visual Studio. It has no impact on NuGet.exe.

Comment: OK thanks, that's already valuable information. I'm interested in both. So since this checkbox has no impact on NuGet.exe, how do you do the same for NuGet.exe?

Comment: There is nothing built in to NuGet.exe to prevent "nuget update -self" from updating itself. Your options will probably be 1) Build your own version of NuGet from source and remove support for the "update -self" option. 2) File permissions on NuGet.exe itself. When you update -self it tries to move nuget.exe to nuget.old and then downloads the new version and replaces nuget.exe.

Comment: Why does it update itself even if I don't run "nuget update -self" but just "nuget" without parameters?
(Thanks for the idea with file permissions.)

Comment: NuGet.exe will only update itself if you run "nuget update -self". Running just "nuget" without any parameters would not update nuget.

Comment: @Peter you might be using the [bootstrapper](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939). You can fix this by replacing it with the actual exe from https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize NuGet.exe / NuGet.exe bootstrapper where two different things / I thought it would only replace itself with the real thing the first time it is run.

Answer (score 0):

To turn off the automatic check for updates, go to the NuGet settings dialog and uncheck Automatically check for updates.
[image]
This feature was actually added in NuGet 1.3, but would not be visible, of course, until an update to 1.3, such as NuGet 1.4, was made available.

Comment: I know, this does not seem to help with the command line though.